# Why do some people declare extern functions inside one function?

Tags: c, function, extern

I need to maintain some code written by others.And I just came across many functions declared inside one function and defined elsewhere.
For example:

```
int func(){
    ...
    extern func1();
    extern func2();
    ...

}
```

Why do they declare and define functions like this?Why don't they declare the functions outside? What's the advantages?

Comment: Personally I think those declarations are a bad idea. Other people agree with me because gcc has an option to warn about them: `-Wnested-externs`.

Comment: I want to know the advantages of this kind of practice.@Maharaj

Comment: Why not? You may not like it, but it's legal C.

Answer (score 6):

It is a very dangerous practice - there is no guarantee that the prototype matches the actual function, and if it doesn't match, all kinds of things can go wrong. Especially the code that actually implements these functions won't see this declaration, which makes it dangerous.

The proper way to do this would be that the author of the two functions would put their declarations into a header file, and the file using them should include that header file. As a rule, each and every C function should be either static, or it should be declared in a header file.

If code is written like this, it is done out of laziness, and possibly out of a desire to lay traps for future developers. You can also see that the declarations use an outdated style: extern func1 () means that func1 returns an int (as the default) and that it takes an unknown but fixed number of parameters. So you (and the compiler) don't even know how to call it.

Let's say the function was implemented as

```
int func1 (int arg)
```

and the implementer decided it should be changed to

```
void func1 (int arg, int* result)
```

returning a value through a pointer, not as the function result. The weird declaration will make sure that the compiler has no chance to detect this, and calling func1 after the change is very likely to crash, or worse to override a random int somewhere in your application. It's a disaster waiting to happen. If you see code like this in your application, fix it immediately.

Answer (score 1):

The only purpose is to reduce scope where external declarations are visible.

Comment: Still not get your point,could you please explain it in detail?@Serhio

Comment: Yeah, but what's the point of reducing the scope?

Comment: @melpomene I guess the point is the same as for other scope-reducing techniques - avoid pollution of global scope with unneeded declarations. But, yes, it is bad idea to do so.

Comment: @Serhio But the global scope is already "polluted". The external symbols are still there if the linker links them in, even if they don't have file scope within a C translation unit.

Comment: @IanAbbott Yes, there is no changes from linker's point of view, but that functions won't be available at compile time in global scope (of course only when implicit declarations are disabled).

Answer (score 1):

The posted sample is actually incorrect, the prototypes should have a return type:

```
int func(void) {
    extern int func1();
    return func1();
}

int func2(void) {
    return func1();  // declaration out of scope
}
```

This **VERY BAD** practice allows the declaration of `func1` to be local to the body of function `func`.  The declaration of `func1` does not have any effect after the end of function `func`.  In practice, modern compilers keep track of such dubious declarations and complain.

It is bad practice because there is no way to verify the consistency of the declaration with the actual definition.  Placing declarations in header files that are included both in the files that **use** and in the file that **defines** the function is the correct way to go.